# How to not display "Clear Filters" when the "All" option is selected in a custom dropdown?

Tags: javascript

In this dropdown menu, I have the option for a 'Clear Filters' bit of text to be displayed if a filtered option is selected. If I click "Clear Filters", then it goes away and all the cards return.

The issue I'm having is I want to **NOT** want to display "Clear Filters" if the 'All' selection is used. If "All" is selected, then all the cards should display.

The full **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/r3hab/pen/wvdBRmb) is here.**

My area of focus is:

```
//clear selection
function clearSelection() {
  document.querySelector(".custom__select-wrapper .story-sel h6").textContent = "STORY TYPE";
  document.querySelector(".custom__select-wrapper .year-sel h6").textContent = "YEAR";
  document.querySelector(".custom__option.selected[data-type]").classList.remove("selected");
  document.querySelector(".custom__option.selected[data-year]").classList.remove("selected");
  document.querySelector(".custom__option[data-type='all']").classList.add("selected");
  document.querySelector(".custom__option[data-year='all']").classList.add("selected");

  selectedFilter.classList.add("hidden");

  let articles = [...document.querySelectorAll(".article")];

  current_story = "all";
  current_year = "all";

  articles.forEach(function (article) {
    article.classList.add("hidden");
    article.classList.add("chosen");
  });
  loadInitial();
  checkLoadMore();
  checkEmpties();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your "reset button" event listener. Instead of adding the `hidden` class and removing the `selected-clearFilter` (not sure what this does...) you can [force-toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) it based on the current selection. Check if both are `"all"`.

```js
//reset button
let filterSelection = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown").forEach(dropdown => {
  dropdown.addEventListener("click", function () {
    let allSelected = current_story === 'all' && current_year === 'all';
    selectedFilter.classList.toggle("hidden", allSelected);
    selectedFilter.classList.toggle('selected-clearFilter', !allSelected)
  })
});
```

Furthermore you should initalize your variables with `"all"`, otherwise this works only after you changed both values at least once.

```js
let current_story = "all",
  current_year = "all";
```